# How to get a class' "public" instance from its definition

Tags: php, oop

Inside the definition of a class' method I include an external file. I would like this external file unable to access `$this`, but only the "public" instance, i.e. only the public methods and properties.

So far I have tried to use anonymous functions, call_user_func with a method returning `$this`.

I have seen I can unset `$this` in my anonymous function without altering the rest of the execution, but I haven't found a way to get the instance as I want it. I think I could try to unset all non-public properties and methods in the anonymous function but I wonder if there is not a simpler way.

```
Class Foo{
    private $test = 23;

    public function getFoo(){
      return $this;
    }

    public function inclFile($file){
      $foo = call_user_func([$this, 'getFoo']);
      $r = function()use($foo){
        unset($this);
        var_dump($foo->test); // i am getting it!
        require($file);
      };
      $r();
      // Here $this is still set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn the design around a bit, and create this function (and place it anywhere):

```
function access_object_in_file($file_to_require, $object) {
    require $file_to_require;
}
```

This will limit the scope of the file to only have access to `$object`. Since PHP is PHP, your file will be allowed to create reflection classes, parse back trace etc but the variable scope is limited to `$object`.

If you do not want any type of objects passed to the function, I would add an interface and type hint for it, such as this:

```
// let's pretend we're in a view layer
function render($view_file, Properties $object) {
    require $file_to_require;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried, but if I call this first function from inside the class, the problem is the same, even if the function is defined outside the class: I have access to private properties

Comment: @nabab that is how `require` (and that family of language constructs) works in php, it basically cuts & pastes the content of one file in the place of the require statement. That is why I suggest that you move out the logic into an empty function (`access_object_in_file()`) so that it has an empty scope, besides the arguments to the function (`$object`) and the file's content.

Comment: Yes I think I understand but this function has to be called from outside the class definition, because if I call it from inside using `$this` as parameter I can still access the private properties from within the function. Now if I have to call the method from outside the class, using the object as parameter I know it will work, but it doesn't fit the logic of my class and it will be a huge mess to change :(

Comment: Did you try to just replace `function()use($foo)` with `function($foo)` in your code? That might be the same as what I'm hinting at, but I'm not too sure about the scope of php's anonymous functions. Edit: replace `$foo` too, with `$foo = $this`. Hm.. not sure that the scope changes but worth a try.

Comment: Sorry, your very first answer was right. I used a static method instead of a function, and the scope was different. If the static method comes from another class or if it is just a function, the scope becomes public. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, thanks for clarifying. The static method should have the same problem as the instance method, but allowing `self::`-anything instead, which makes sense together with what you are saying.